# Do I have to pay to use TFS (setting up my own TFS server on private azure VM)?

Tags: azure, tfs

As of now, do I have to pay anything to use TFS (the software), by installing / setting up a TFS server on a private VM on Azure.

I have multiple projects that are multiple hundreds of MBs to more than 1 GB per project.
Do I need to pay or license to just use/run the software and set up my own code hosting on the cloud (I know I have to pay for the Azure instance)?

Comment: Did you look at using VSTS? It is free for the first 5 users, and you can have multiple projects. I'm not aware of size restrictions

Comment: Hi kvitas, any update on this?

Comment: Sorry, I hvn't done the set up. I am thinking of just using git from Visual Studio 2017 and using the benefit of DVCS. But I'm still murky on that too tbh.. sorry

Comment: @kvitas Using git only from VS locally have huge limitations. VSTS is the cloud offering that provides a scalable, reliable, and globally available hosted service. It is backed by a 99.9% SLA, monitored by our 24-7 operations team, and available in local data centers around the world. It provide an integrated, collaborative environment that supports Git, continuous integration, and Agile tools for planning and tracking work. Since you are working on Azure, it's also easily to deploy to Azure. Take a look at https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.sg%2F

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT I dont know. I used git and set up gitlab, so I can't test your solution at this time. I'll let the community to vote.. But thx for your answer btw.

Answer (score 1):

If you paid Windows Server Vms, then you do not have. Instead of making a 3-year purchasing commitment for TFS server, you could use modern purchasing.

> You can pay month-to-month and cancel any time. Here’s how:
>
> Run TFS in a Windows Server VM on Azure: [Windows Server VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/services/virtual-machines/)
>   **include the Windows Server licensing costs**, providing a flexible way for you to choose the right size VM for your TFS performance needs
>   and pay monthly for this usage.

More details info please refer: *[Team Foundation Server Pricing](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/)*

You could also double confirm this by contacting the sales team of TFS/Azure:

- [TFS support](https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-support/)
- [Microsoft Azure pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/)